# How do i Set the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel> to Ignore CERT Errors

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-5

I am moving an application that communicates with a WCF service from .net 4.8 to net5 i ran the utility SvcUtil.exe (importing a WDSL File) which generated the Reference.cs file which created the classes and object from the WSDL file. In net5 it is now using the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase class to interact with the WCF Service, where as in net48 it was using 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol'. Code compiles but there remains two problems that I'm experiencing right now that i cannot seem to find the answer for using the new 'System.ServiceModel.ClientBase' implementation generated by the SvcUtil.exe tool.

1. When the connection is trying to be established i am always getting the following Exception:

   {"Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'."} InnerException => {"The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."} InnerException => {"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors"}
2. Also the in the net48 version i store the cookie in the cookie container like So:

   ```
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieParts[0], cookieParts[1], 
                                    serviceUri.LocalPath, serviceUri.Host);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            _xieServiceRef.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            _xieServiceRef.CookieContainer.Add(serviceUri, cookie);
   ```

My problem is that for one in net48 to tell the service to ignore all cert errors we execute the following code

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
```

From anywhere in the app and we bypass those errors. But in net5 you have to approach it differently and the only example is given using the HttpClient class and you create the HttpClient with a defined HttpClientHandler callback as in the example below this will ignore the CERT errors just as the code above for net48.

```
var EndPoint = "https://192.168.0.1/api";
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    return true;
};
httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(EndPoint) };
```

In using the SvcUtil.exe generated code with the use of the ClientBase class as a means of interaction with the WCF Service, I cannot find methods or example similar to the above code to ignore the CERT errors. I also cannot find the Cookie Container for the ClientBase either. Do I need to skip using the generated code from SvcUtil.exe and switch to the HttpClient instead of the ClientBase. Or are there similar ways to store the generated cookie and ignore the CERT errors. We don't control the API we are calling and there is no REST version of the API and none coming soon so we are stuck working with what we have.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and also thank you ahead of time

**UPDATE**
So i did some more research and digging and i have found that using the following code:

```
    //Right Here we are creating the Service Object
    XIEserviceClient _xieServiceRef = null;
    _xieServiceRef = new XIEserviceClient();
    _xieServiceRef.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
    {
        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
    };
    _xieServiceRef.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = CalderaConfiguration.SelectedOS4000ApiConnection.Username;
    _xieServiceRef.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = CalderaConfiguration.SelectedOS4000ApiConnection.Password;
```

We are now able to bypass the cert errors.

Now I'm just trying to I'm to figure out the whole cookie/authentication error, I now get the following Exception:

```
"The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)
```

This i believe, according to Fiddler, appears to be an authentication issue because it appears that a login page is being returned from the service i believe this is the cookie issue I'm still looking into....

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider :

1. Do you have DNS and line-of-sight to the server?
2. Are you using the correct name from the certificate?
3. Is the certificate still valid?
4. Is a badly configured load balancer messing things up?
5. Does the new server machine have the clock set correctly (i.e. so that the UTC time is correct [ignore local time, it is largely irrelevent]) - this certainly matters for WCF, so may impact regular SOAP?
6. Is there a certificate trust chain issue? if you browse from the server to the soap service, can you get SSL?
7. Related to the above - has the certificate been installed to the correct location? (you may need a copy in Trusted Root Certification Authorities)
8. is the server's machine-level proxy set correctly? (which different to the user's proxy);see proxycfg for XP / 2003 (not sure about Vista etc)

Comment: Answers to Above:

Comment: @MPreston - Stack overflow [does not work like a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110).  Each post is intended to be a question, or an answer.  So you should add that information to your question.